# Error message on enabling read permission on opportunity

Tags: error, error-messages

I am getting below error message when enabling Read permission on Opportunity object for a profile. Any one knows that this means?

> Permission Read Real Time Evaluation Method Elements depends on
>   permission(s): Read Real Time Call Definitions

Anyone ever encountered this error before?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Never mind.. The issue has been resolved. It seems an object inside a managed package was causing the issue. Sort of a dependent permission needed. Object name was Real Time Call Definitions. Unless i gave the read permission on this custom managed package object, it wouldnt allow me to give any permissions on other objects that were involved in the flow.

Managed package in question: Quote2Win
Error on Opportunity object Read permission grant.

Hope this helps in case anyone else faces it.